# Does CanvasRenderingContext2D.measureText() change with the current transformation?

Tags: javascript, canvas

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics/width), `.measureText().width` "contains the text's advance width (the width of that inline box) in CSS pixels", which means the display size on the screen, meaning that if I call `.scale(2,2)` on the canvas before I call `.measureText()`, I will get a width twice as large.  However, my tests on Chrome suggests that `.measureText()` does not change when I scale the canvas.  It appears to me that `.measureText()` returns the same thing even if I call the function on a different canvas, as long as the string used is the same.

Am I reading MDN wrong, and can I expect all modern browsers to work the same way as Chrome?

Why I asked this question:

I'm trying use an off-screen canvas for pre-rendering, but the width of the off-screen canvas is determined by how much text I need to display.  Thus, it would seem preferable that I call `.measureText()` on my main canvas before creating the off-screen canvas.

Comment: CSS pixel is an unit. It doesn't mean that it will be the size rendered. For your issue you'll have to keep track of the current scaleX and do `measureText().width() * scaleX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSS pixel is an abstracted pixel size/unit on top of actual physical pixels. If we zoom a browser window to say 200%, something defined as 100px CSS pixels will still be 100px CSS pixels, but it will occupy 200 physical pixels.

So when the result is returned in CSS pixels it means the size is unaffected by things such as scale.

It should therefor be safe to assume you will get the same size for the font regardless of the current transform on the canvas *context*.

And it's easy to validate:

```js
var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "20px sans-serif";
console.log("Scale 100%", ctx.measureText("WWW").width);
ctx.scale(2,2);
console.log("Scale 200%", ctx.measureText("WWW").width);
```

In Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

In Blink engine (here Opera):

[image: Blink]

IE11:

[image: IE11]

And so on. The size is equal despite scale transform has been applied (the slight different numbers between browsers has to do with the font engine the browser is using and how it calculates/render fonts).